# how to update columns with values of sub select query using same column in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

i have a table table i need to update column(s) using a sub query that makes uses of the same column and the same table it keeps throwing errors

> #1093 - You can't specify target table 'userdata' for update in FROM clause

this is my table structure

```
#   first_name  username        user_id     manager     employer
1   Obey        Obeytalbot      5KNHEZW22P  joekenpat   joekenpat
2   Venantius   Philian         AYL67CIA8A  MVKO6BLZL1  MVKO6BLZL1
3   Chidinma    Chidinma        7LEJG9VQKN  LUWY0AQ218  LUWY0AQ218
4   Victor      Victron         CQIIKUHME4  LUWY0AQ218  LUWY0AQ218
5   Francis     FrancisRapheal  LKDCRH3OAT  OP4R245PX7  OP4R245PX7
```

what i want to do is update `manager / employer` column, using a select statement: where the value of the `manager / employer` column is = `user_id` column then return the `username` of the row as the result to update `manager / employer` field

here is what i have tried:

```
UPDATE 
    userdata 
set 
    manager = (
        SELECT username from userdata 
        where user_id = manager LIMIT 1
    ),
employer = (
        SELECT username from userdata 
        where user_id = employer LIMIT 1
    )
```

Comment: Share the query which you have tried and it would be great if you add expected result.

Comment: @James  i just did an edit now thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a self join in the update statement:

```
update userdata u1
inner join userdata u2 on u2.user_id in (u1.manager, u1.employer)
set 
  u1.manager = case when u1.manager = u2.user_id then u2.username else u1.manager end, 
  u1.employer = case when u1.employer = u2.user_id then u2.username else u1.employer end
```